# support needed with php contact form script

Tags: php, email

i need help with  a  php contact form script.the problem is when i run it i don`t receive emails  when i use contact form.i was in the hope someone can tell me where the problem is located find code  below. i run it in test php  and got this message. i appreciate if anyone can help

```
    <php




/* Email Variables */
$emailSubject = 'indie music!'; 
$webMaster = 'myemail';



/* Data Variables */
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];



$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Comments: $comments <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);



$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>sent message</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=mydomain">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #444; 
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fec001;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 200px;
margin-left: 150px;
width: 800px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<div align="center"> message has been successfully sent you will be contacted shortly</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

Comment: where you run this script ? on live server or local server?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change `$webMaster` to a valid recipient email address?

Make sure you're running those script in web hosting. Localhost doesn't execute PHP `mail` function.

If you're already running on web hosting, make sure mail doesn't go into spam/junk email.

Comment: hi everyone yes the webmaster has a valid email.i am running the script on a web hosting.when i  use form i get this message  
your message has been successfully sent we will contact you shortly but i get no emal  . i also tested the script on a php  script testing site and got this <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '<' on line <b>1</b><br />

Comment: well, I didn't notice your line 1 `<php` change it to `<?php`